# Transposing identical objects

Tags: r, matrix, transpose

I got a weird result today.

To replicate it,  consider the following data frames:

```
x <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=11:13)
y <- x[1:3, 1:2]
```

They are supposed to be and actually are identical:

```
identical(x,y)
# [1] TRUE
```

Applying  `t()` to indentical objects should produce the same result, but:

```
identical(t(x),t(y))
# [1] FALSE
```

The difference is in the column names:

```
colnames(t(x))
# NULL
colnames(t(y))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Given this, if you want to stack `y` by columns, you get what you'd expect:

```
stack(as.data.frame(t(y)))
#   values ind
# 1      1   1
# 2     11   1
# 3      2   2
# 4     12   2
# 5      3   3
# 6     13   3
```

while:

```
stack(as.data.frame(t(x)))
#     values ind
# 1      1  V1
# 2     11  V1
# 3      2  V2
# 4     12  V2
# 5      3  V3
# 6     13  V3
```

In the latter case,  `as.data.frame()` does not find the original column names and automatically generates them.

The culprit is in `as.matrix()`,  called by `t()`:

```
rownames(as.matrix(x))
# NULL
rownames(as.matrix(y))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

A workaround is to set `rownames.force`:

```
rownames(as.matrix(x, rownames.force=TRUE))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
rownames(as.matrix(y, rownames.force=TRUE))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
identical(t(as.matrix(x, rownames.force=TRUE)), 
          t(as.matrix(y, rownames.force=TRUE)))
# [1] TRUE
```

(and rewrite  `stack(...)` call accordingly.)

My questions are:

1. Why `as.matrix()` treats differently `x` and `y` and
2. how can you tell the difference between them?

Note that other info functions do not reveal differences between `x, y`:

```
identical(attributes(x), attributes(y))
# [1] TRUE
identical(str(x), str(y))
# ...
#[1] TRUE
```

## Comments to solutions

[Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43212381/1851270) gives a concise but effective explanation to the behaviour outlined above (see also [mt1022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211989/1851270)
 for more details).

In short Konrad shows that:

a) `x` and `y` are *internally* different;
b) "`identical` is too  is simply too lax by default" to catch this internal difference.

Now, if  you take a subset `T` of the set `S`, which has *all* the elements of `S`, then `S` and `T`  are exactly the same objects. So, if you take a data frame `y`, which has *all* the rows and columns of `x`, then `x` and `y`  *should be*  exactly the same objects. Unfortunately `x \neq y`!
This behaviour is not only  counterintuitive but also obfuscated, that is, the  difference is not self evident, but only *internal* and even the default `identical` function can't see it.

Another natural principle is that transposing two identical (matrix-like) objects produces identical objects.  Again, this is broken by the fact that, before transposing,  `identical` is "too lax"; after transposing, the default  `identical` is enough to see the difference.

IMHO  this behaviour (even if it is not a bug) is a misbehaviour for a scientific language like R.
*Hopefully this post will drive some attention and the R team will consider to revise it.*

Comment: seems to be how the `row.names` are defined , as they are different in `dput(x)`, and `dput(y`). Maybe they are explicitly added when using ``[.data.frame``

Comment: You can use dput(x) and dput(y) and you will see that the row.names are stored in a different way. I think it's related to automatic row.names handling (check https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html details section for further info), no idea why subsetting returns different row.names though... and to be honest, it smells like an unexpected behavior to me

Comment: `identical(x, y, attrib.as.set=FALSE)` seems to pick up on differences ( noting the line in `?identical` "*Note that identical(x, y, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) pickily tests for exact equality."*

Comment: The difference arises in as.matrix when it calls `.row_names_info` and as @digEmAll pointed out is because of the automatic row names in `x`.

Comment: As it's written, `as.matrix` removes automatic row names so that they don't end up as row names in the matrix.

Comment: "row.names" are either stored as a `length == nrow(x)` vector or as a compact form of type `c(NA, -nrow(x))` to avoid creating and carrying a `as.character(1:nrow(x))` vector around. When subsetting "x", `"[.data.frame"` has to create some form of `row.names` for the subsetted "x". Even if `x[c(1, 2, 3), ]` seems to not need "row.names", something like `x[c(2, 3, 1), ]` needs and `"[.data.frame"` needs to be consistent regarding its output...

Comment: ...Nonetheles, R can see that in the first case, "row.names" are in increasing order hence it is stored as `c(NA, nrow(x))` (the object _has_ "row.names" but there's no need to create `1:nrow(x)`). In the second case a "row.names" attribute as `c(2, 3, 1)` has to be created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`identical` is simply too lax by default but you can change that:

```
> identical(x, y, attrib.as.set = FALSE)
[1] FALSE
```

The reason can be found by inspecting the objects in more detail:

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(x = 1:3, y = 11:13), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA,
-3L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(y)
structure(list(x = 1:3, y = 11:13), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA,
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note the distinct `row.names` attributes:

```
> .row_names_info(x)
[1] -3
> .row_names_info(y)
[1] 3
```

From the documentation we can glean that a negative number implies automatic rownames (for `x`), whereas `y`’s row names aren’t automatic. And `as.matrix` treats them differently.

Comment: No disagreement. The help page for `row.names` says "Row names of the form 1:n for n > 2 are stored internally in a compact form,.." and that `as.matrix`  and "other functions" will   "handle [names of this sort] differently." Running trace('row.names') shows that it was called 3 times for the questioner's example (at least once there was a call to `print(y`)).  It also says: "`row.names` will always return a character vector. (Use `attr(x, "row.names")`  if you need to retrieve an integer-valued set of row names.)".

Comment: `row.names = c(NA,3L)` still produces row.names automatically as well as `row.names = c(NA,-3L)`. The question is, why subsetting the data.frame changes the sign (and consequently causes the difference) ?

Comment: @digEmAll : `c(NA, -3L)` seems to mark the object as not having explicit "row.names" (i.e. not set or set to `NULL`) which means, that a function accouning for a data.frame's "row.names" should ignore this attribute. `c(NA, 3L)` seems to mark the object as having explicit "row.names" but of the form `1:nrow(x)` which can be spared from creating. `"[.data.frame"` returns a subset of the data as well a subset of its "row.names" (e.g. `x[2:3, ]`'s "row.names" cannot be stored compactly), and it seems that the most consistent way to behave is to, always, return an object with explicit "row.names".

Answer (score 3):

As in comment, `x` and `y` are not strictly the same. When we call `t` to `data.frame`, `t.data.frame` will be executed:

```
function (x) 
{
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    NextMethod("t")
}
```

As we can see, it calls `as.matrix`, i.e. `as.matrix.data.frame`:

```
function (x, rownames.force = NA, ...) 
{
    dm <- dim(x)
    rn <- if (rownames.force %in% FALSE) 
        NULL
    else if (rownames.force %in% TRUE) 
        row.names(x)
    else if (.row_names_info(x) <= 0L) 
        NULL
    else row.names(x)
...
```

As commented by @oropendola, the return of `.row_names_info` of `x` and `y` are different and The above function is where the difference takes effect.

Then why `y` has different `rownames`? Let's look at `[.data.frame`, I have added comment at key lines:

```
{
    ... # many lines of code
    xx <- x  #!! this is where xx is defined
    cols <- names(xx)
    x <- vector("list", length(x))
    x <- .Internal(copyDFattr(xx, x))  # This is where I am not sure about
    oldClass(x) <- attr(x, "row.names") <- NULL
    if (has.j) {
        nm <- names(x)
        if (is.null(nm)) 
            nm <- character()
        if (!is.character(j) && anyNA(nm)) 
            names(nm) <- names(x) <- seq_along(x)
        x <- x[j]
        cols <- names(x)
        if (drop && length(x) == 1L) {
            if (is.character(i)) {
                rows <- attr(xx, "row.names")
                i <- pmatch(i, rows, duplicates.ok = TRUE)
            }
            xj <- .subset2(.subset(xx, j), 1L)
            return(if (length(dim(xj)) != 2L) xj[i] else xj[i, 
                                                            , drop = FALSE])
        }
        if (anyNA(cols)) 
            stop("undefined columns selected")
        if (!is.null(names(nm))) 
            cols <- names(x) <- nm[cols]
        nxx <- structure(seq_along(xx), names = names(xx))
        sxx <- match(nxx[j], seq_along(xx))
    }
    else sxx <- seq_along(x)
    rows <- NULL ## this is where rows is defined, as we give numeric i, the following
    ## if block will not be executed
    if (is.character(i)) {
        rows <- attr(xx, "row.names")
        i <- pmatch(i, rows, duplicates.ok = TRUE)
    }
    for (j in seq_along(x)) {
        xj <- xx[[sxx[j]]]
        x[[j]] <- if (length(dim(xj)) != 2L) 
            xj[i]
        else xj[i, , drop = FALSE]
    }
    if (drop) {
        n <- length(x)
        if (n == 1L) 
            return(x[[1L]])
        if (n > 1L) {
            xj <- x[[1L]]
            nrow <- if (length(dim(xj)) == 2L) 
                dim(xj)[1L]
            else length(xj)
            drop <- !mdrop && nrow == 1L
        }
        else drop <- FALSE
    }
    if (!drop) { ## drop is False for our case
        if (is.null(rows)) 
            rows <- attr(xx, "row.names")  ## rows changed from NULL to 1,2,3 here
        rows <- rows[i]
        if ((ina <- anyNA(rows)) | (dup <- anyDuplicated(rows))) {
            if (!dup && is.character(rows)) 
                dup <- "NA" %in% rows
            if (ina) 
                rows[is.na(rows)] <- "NA"
            if (dup) 
                rows <- make.unique(as.character(rows))
        }
        if (has.j && anyDuplicated(nm <- names(x))) 
            names(x) <- make.unique(nm)
        if (is.null(rows)) 
            rows <- attr(xx, "row.names")[i]
        attr(x, "row.names") <- rows  ## this is where the rownames of x changed
        oldClass(x) <- oldClass(xx)
    }
    x
}
```

we can see that `y` get its names by something like `attr(x, 'row.names')`:

```
> attr(x, 'row.names')
[1] 1 2 3
```

So when we created `y` with `[.data.frame`, it receives  `row.names` attributes that are different from `x`, of which the `row.names` are automatic and indicated with negative sign in `dput` results.

---

## edit

Actually, this has been stated in manual of [`row.names`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html):

> Note
>
> row.names is similar to rownames for arrays, and it has a method that
>   calls rownames for an array argument.
>
> Row names of the form 1:n for n > 2 are stored internally in a compact
>   form, which might be seen from C code or by deparsing but never via
>   row.names or attr(x, "row.names"). Additionally, some names of this
>   sort are marked as ‘automatic’ and handled differently by as.matrix
>   and data.matrix (and potentially other functions).

So `attr` doesn't discriminate between automatic `row.names` (like that of `x`) and explicit interger `row.names` (like that of `y`), while this is discriminated by `as.matrix` through internal representation `.row_names_info`.

Comment: Something worth noting is that `attr(x, "row.names")` and `attr(x, "row.names") = value` do not show how R, internally, handles the specific case of "row.names". `.row_names_info` is more accurate. E.g. `attr(x, "row.names") = 1:3` does not store `1:3` as "row.names" but as shown in `.row_names_info(x, 0)`.  Still, though, anythign other than `NULL` flags the object as having user-defined "row.names" hence functions (like `as.matrix`) need to/should take this into account.

Comment: sure. `attr(x, 'row.names')` and `attr(y, 'row.names')` gives the same results!